# Given NOW(), How Do You Obtain DATETIME Object Of First Day In Week in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

What would be the best way to obtain a DATETIME object of the first day of the week, given the input of NOW() in MySQL? It would be great if the first day of the week could be set as input in case the first day of the week is 'Sunday' or 'Monday'.

I'm looking to feed this into DATE_FORMAT using pseudo code like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(<first_day_of_week_datetime_object>, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of the week:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(subdate(now(), INTERVAL weekday(now()) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Last day of the week:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(adddate(now(), INTERVAL 6-weekday(now()) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the first day of the week is to do:

```
select date_sub(datecol, interval - weekday(datecol) day)
```

MySQL has the week starting on Monday.  I see no reason to format this as a string.